# Getting Robinhood options data in PHP

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, php-curl

I'm trying to get Robinhood option data in PHP, which requires authentication. I feel like I am a breath away from my solution, but after trying for a day I am ready to ask for help.

So far, I have been able to log in to Robinhood and get the token, then use that token to authenticate a request for a second (oauth) token successfully. But for some reason, I am unable to get options data for the option of my choice (MSFT Put 75 Exp 1/17/2020, found here with proper authentication https://api.robinhood.com/marketdata/options/0fd40096-9cbc-4b14-9df4-c1c9ea5f5729/ )

Here is how I login

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.robinhood.com/api-token-auth/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=example@gmail.com&password=mypassword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
$result = json_decode($server_output);
$token = $result->token;
curl_close ($ch);
```

Then I take that token and convert it

```
$url = 'https://api.robinhood.com/oauth2/migrate_token/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Token '.$token));
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
$result = json_decode($server_output);
$oauth_token = $result->access_token;
curl_close ($ch);
```

Up to here so far so good, but I am only getting a blank response when I try the following:

```
$url = 'https://api.robinhood.com/marketdata/options/0fd40096-9cbc-4b14-9df4-c1c9ea5f5729/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$oauth_token));
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Any help or ideas why I'm having issues on the last part would be immensely appreciated :)

EDIT: In answer to WebCode.ie, the result of print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) is:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://api.robinhood.com/marketdata/options/0fd40096-
cbc-4b14-9df4-c1c9ea5f5729/
    [content_type] => application/json
    [http_code] => 405
    [header_size] => 187
    [request_size] => 453
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.386518
    [namelookup_time] => 2.8E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.094845
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.289176
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.386491
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] =>
    [primary_ip] => 52.200.3.207
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 84.x.x.x //my IP
    [local_port] => 60974
)
```

Comment: What does `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` show you on your last call?

Comment: It was too long to comment so I appended it to the original question. Looks like I am getting a 405 which at least indicates I am asking the right endpoint :)

Comment: OK, HTTP 405 is mehtod not allowed. So perhaps try using GET instead of POST. Remove this line from your last call: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` let me know if it works for you. Curiously, what does their docs say for the method that should be used?

Comment: I LOVE YOU. It works! There is no documentation, I'm just using various Github projects people have reverse engineered.

Comment: lol, no problem, best of luck with it!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.

@Mark is there a new login method?

Comment: I created a python script which exports robinhood stock and options data to excel. Here you go:

https://github.com/arungeorge101/myRobinhoodData

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was making POST call when I should have been making a GET call. If you are having trouble remove this line from my last code block.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```